# How should I interpret my exponential regression model SPSS output?

Tags: spss, nonlinear-regression

I am analyzing Log+C transformed intensity data with temperature. I was advised to do a curve estimation regression analysis in SPSS, examining an exponential relationship but I am not sure how to interpret my output.  My sample size is small- only 10, but the relationship, the curve, appears strong to me.  Here is my output with the exponential model [image: SPSS output]

Comment: Your tables look not at all like those from SPSS Curve estimation procedure. Are mixing something up?

Answer (score 1):

That looks exactly like the CURVEFIT (Analyze > Regression > Curve Estimation) output to me.  It is the estimates for the regression of ln(Transfintensity) on High, i.e.,
ln(Trnsfintensity) = 7856642 - .651 * High.

so exponentiating both sides gives
Transfintensity = e**(7856642 - .651 * High).
There is an optional plot with this procedure that might help you understand the equation